# Tron Network Contract Read-Only Method Fees

Tags: blockchain, smartcontracts, tron

Does it cost anything to call a Smart Contract on Tron that returns data from the contract but does NOT change any data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you call it.

The [eth_call](https://eth.wiki/json-rpc/API#eth_call) JSON-RPC method is free.

The [eth_sendTransaction](https://eth.wiki/json-rpc/API#eth_sendTransaction) method creates a transaction and consumes gas in the form of native currency (in case of the Tron network, that's TRX).

Some wallet apps only support the transaction mode and do not support calls. Some JSON-RPC wrapper libraries such as [web3js](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.4/) allow you to chose between the call (using the library `.call()` method) and the transaction (using the library `.send()` method).

*Note: Even though the methods are prepended `eth_`, they are used on the Tron network as well.*

Comment: Thanks again Petr! I was pretty sure there was a call mechanism that keeps dApp reads free. I guess I'm curious now how a DDOS attack or just generally high read application is treated...

Comment: DDOS protection is usually implemented on the JSON-RPC provider. They usually have a public API acting as a "middleware" before the actual request to the Tron daemon... So I can imagine there's protection on a router level, as well as on the HTTP server (e.g. nginx) for their public API "middleware". Most providers also use rate limiting of how many requests per sec/min can each (valid) API key request... Only if the request is not stopped by the previous steps, the API "middleware" sends the `eth_*` request to the Tron daemon running on their (other) server, and proxies back the response.